# Parsing *.nmea file with QNmeaPositionInfoSource class returns timeout.

Tags: c++, qt, gps, nmea

I'm trying to write simple application which is going to simulate GPS hardware device basing on already taken `*.nmea` log file. Technology which I chose is Qt5.4.1. because it already got class which should take care of the task which I'm trying to do. Class name is `QNmeaPositionInfoSource`. 
I supposed that by setting proper update interval timeout instance of `QNmeaPositionInfoSource` will notify me about new position. However, when I set interval to the `1s` I'm getting only one position and after that timeout is notified. When I set interval to the `0`, I'm getting immediatelly all notifications about position.

Please find a code of my program below:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QNmeaPositionInfoSource>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    logFile = new QFile(":/files/dummy.nmea");
    nmeaSource = new QNmeaPositionInfoSource(
        QNmeaPositionInfoSource::SimulationMode);
    nmeaSource->setDevice(logFile);
    nmeaSource->setUpdateInterval(1000);
    connect(nmeaSource, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
            this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
    connect(nmeaSource, SIGNAL(updateTimeout()), this, SLOT(updateTimeout()));
    connect(nmeaSource,SIGNAL(error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error)),
            this,SLOT(error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error)));
    nmeaSource->startUpdates();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo positionInfo)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    qDebug() << QString("Lat: %1").arg(QString::number(positionInfo.coordinate().latitude()));
    qDebug() << QString("Lon: %1").arg(QString::number(positionInfo.coordinate().longitude()));
}

void MainWindow::updateTimeout(void)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

void MainWindow::error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error positioningError)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    qDebug() << QString::number(positioningError);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>

class QFile;
class QNmeaPositionInfoSource;
//class QGeoPositionInfoSource;

namespace Ui
{
        class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFile *logFile;
    QNmeaPositionInfoSource *nmeaSource;
private slots:
        void positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo positionInfo);
        void updateTimeout(void);
        void error(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error positioningError);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

dummy.nmea

```
$GPGGA,222437.000,2734.33926,S,15305.44310,E,1,07,1.3,50.6,M,39.2,M,,*72
$GPGLL,2734.33926,S,15305.44310,E,222437.000,A,A*49
$GPGSA,A,3,16,25,23,20,13,27,11,,,,,,2.3,1.3,1.9*3D
$GPGST,222437.000,13.3,7.4,6.6,85.1,6.0,6.8,13.7*56
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,49,115,42,25,39,269,36,23,58,176,29,20,72,335,35*75
$GPGSV,3,2,10,19,02,028,,04,06,241,22,13,30,223,30,27,19,284,35*78
$GPGSV,3,3,10,11,06,337,30,03,13,055,25*7C
$GPRMC,222437.000,A,2734.33926,S,15305.44310,E,33.9,157.8,030308,11.2,W,A*0F
$GPVTG,157.8,T,169.0,M,33.9,N,62.9,K,A*22
$GPGGA,222438.000,2734.34821,S,15305.44697,E,1,07,1.2,50.8,M,39.2,M,,*79
$GPGLL,2734.34821,S,15305.44697,E,222438.000,A,A*4D
$GPGSA,A,3,16,25,23,20,13,27,03,,,,,,2.1,1.2,1.7*33
$GPGST,222438.000,12.4,6.4,9.3,16.2,6.1,8.3,16.4*5F
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,49,115,41,25,39,269,36,23,58,176,28,20,72,335,36*74
$GPGSV,3,2,10,19,02,028,,04,06,241,20,13,30,223,28,27,19,284,35*73
$GPGSV,3,3,10,11,06,337,28,03,13,055,25*75
$GPRMC,222438.000,A,2734.34821,S,15305.44697,E,33.8,158.3,030308,11.2,W,A*0E
$GPVTG,158.3,T,169.5,M,33.8,N,62.5,K,A*2E
$GPGGA,222439.000,2734.35696,S,15305.45072,E,1,06,1.7,51.2,M,39.2,M,,*78
$GPGLL,2734.35696,S,15305.45072,E,222439.000,A,A*43
$GPGSA,A,3,16,25,23,20,13,27,,,,,,,3.3,1.7,2.8*3A
$GPGST,222439.000,10.3,9.1,12.2,44.6,9.8,9.9,25.2*62
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,49,115,34,25,39,269,36,23,58,175,29,20,72,335,35*77
$GPGSV,3,2,10,19,02,028,,04,06,241,20,13,30,223,27,27,19,284,32*7B
$GPGSV,3,3,10,11,06,337,28,03,14,055,25*72
$GPRMC,222439.000,A,2734.35696,S,15305.45072,E,33.2,158.7,030308,11.2,W,A*0E
$GPVTG,158.7,T,169.9,M,33.2,N,61.5,K,A*2F
$GPGGA,222440.000,2734.36580,S,15305.45446,E,1,07,1.3,52.0,M,39.2,M,,*76
$GPGLL,2734.36580,S,15305.45446,E,222440.000,A,A*49
$GPGSA,A,3,16,25,23,20,13,27,11,,,,,,2.3,1.3,1.9*3D
$GPGST,222440.000,13.0,8.0,13.4,6.2,7.4,12.2,20.9*64
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,49,115,40,25,39,269,38,23,58,175,31,20,72,335,34*72
$GPGSV,3,2,10,19,02,028,,04,06,241,20,13,30,223,26,27,19,284,30*78
$GPGSV,3,3,10,11,06,337,26,03,14,055,25*7C
$GPRMC,222440.000,A,2734.36580,S,15305.45446,E,33.7,159.1,030308,11.2,W,A*06
$GPVTG,159.1,T,170.3,M,33.7,N,62.4,K,A*2D
$GPGGA,222441.000,2734.37483,S,15305.45825,E,1,07,1.3,52.7,M,39.2,M,,*7A
$GPGLL,2734.37483,S,15305.45825,E,222441.000,A,A*42
$GPGSA,A,3,16,25,23,20,13,27,11,,,,,,2.3,1.3,1.9*3D
$GPGST,222441.000,14.0,7.6,14.1,17.6,7.7,12.5,21.0*51
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,49,115,41,25,39,269,39,23,58,175,29,20,72,335,35*7A
$GPGSV,3,2,10,19,02,028,,04,06,241,20,13,30,223,24,27,19,284,30*7A
$GPGSV,3,3,10,11,06,337,28,03,14,055,25*72
$GPRMC,222441.000,A,2734.37483,S,15305.45825,E,34.6,159.4,030308,11.2,W,A*0E
$GPVTG,159.4,T,170.6,M,34.6,N,64.1,K,A*28
$GPGGA,222442.000,2734.38407,S,15305.46216,E,1,06,1.3,53.3,M,39.2,M,,*77
$GPGLL,2734.38407,S,15305.46216,E,222442.000,A,A*4B
$GPGSA,A,3,16,25,20,13,27,11,,,,,,,2.3,1.3,1.9*3C
$GPGST,222442.000,16.6,7.0,14.4,14.6,7.0,12.8,21.6*5A
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,49,115,40,25,39,269,38,23,58,175,22,20,72,335,35*71
```

Question is why I'm getting timeout notification?

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm trying the same thing with the same problem: only updateTimeout() is called. And it never recovers from that. I've tried to filter out everything except GPGGA and GPRMC as suggest by the other answer but it didn't fix this. And removing or changing the update interval didn't so either. Thanks

Comment: Nope, I didn't fixed this, I've just written nmea parser on my own. Just take a look inside Qt sources it's good base for this task.

Comment: Just linking to the ticket you opened: [QTBUG-51824](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51824)

Answer (score 0):

Encounter with the same problem.

It will work as it have to if you leave only $GPGGA and $GPRMC lines in NMEA file. 
$GPVTG do cause the problem you've described, $GPGSV - don't (so you can leave it too, not important).
Other NMEA messages I haven't tested separately.

"Pure" NMEA file work perfectly as describe in help: even without calling setUpdateInterval() (apparently same as with zero argument) you'll get update intervals according to timestamps in NMEA lines.

This obviously Qt bug. Even if you run GeoFlickr example on Desktop (so that program start work with QNmeaPositionInfoSource in SimulationMode), you'll see that pressing "locate & update" button show latitude and longitude data only once on first click. After that it show "retrieving update" and nothing happens, but according to code it should.

Another confirmatory that the case is may be only in $GPVTG messages: I used instead of your "dummy.nmea" the "nmealog.txt" from GeoFlickr example and I had two calls of positionUpdated before timeout. One for $GPGGA and one for $GPRMC. However in your "dummy.nmea" there is only one message $GPRMC before $GPVTG, so you notified only one call of positionUpdated.

(just in case play with that on Qt5.5.1 on Windows 7)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've tried to filter my input stream to only feature GPGGA and GPRMC. But it was until I removed GPRMC that I at least got an error response other than timeout saying: date & time not available. Which suggests it does process the nmea stream but doesn't signal correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through the Qt sources and came to the following conclusion.
If you comment the line `nmeaSource->setUpdateInterval(1000);` or set 0 value, the example will work as expected, because the documentation to **QGeoPositionInfoSource** says:

> If the update interval is not set (or is set to 0) the source will provide updates as often as necessary.

Inspite the fact that you set non-zero value to `setUpdateInterval()` function in **SimulationMode** the source file (dummy.nmea) is read all at once so there is no new data available to read and that's why timeout happens. Few lines from Qt sources:

```
// some data may already be available
if (m_updateMode == QNmeaPositionInfoSource::SimulationMode) {
    if (m_nmeaReader && m_device->bytesAvailable())
        m_nmeaReader->readAvailableData();
```

I'm not sure whether it is a bug or not but it i think some information can be added regarding this to the Qt documentation.